# Average Value of a function $f_{avg}$

Tags: integration, functions

Let $f_{avg}$ be the average value of a continuous function f(x) on the interval [a,b]. Assume that there's only one c $\in$ [a , b] for which $f(c)=f_{avg}$. The question is, if this is the case, then must the function be either increasing or decreasing on [a, b]? This questions seems to jump from the assumption that $f(c)=f_{avg}$ for 1 value of c to the conclusion above, and I'm having trouble making sense of the question - obviously this is about the average value of a function, which is denoted by $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, but how does it relate to whether the function is increasing or decreasing? One way I know of finding out is by taking the derivative of f(x), but we don't know what f is in the first place. So...plz help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking for the proof and how can you come up with it. 
In case you ask for intuitive understanding, if there is only one $c$ for which $f$ is the average value of the function, it means that even the slightest and the smallest change in the derivative of $f$ locally at some point that is not $c$ won't change the average value and therefore $c$ will still be the single argument for such $f$

$$\exists_{c\in(a, b)} \forall_{x\in[a, b]} \; \lim_{x\rightarrow k}F(x)=F(k),f(c)=\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a} \implies f'(x)\geq 0 \;(f'(x) \leq 0)$$

The thing is that you might assume that there is such $k \in [a,b]$ for which the implication is wrong 
 What left is to check if the assumption doesn't refutes what we are starting with

$$\exists_{c\neq d\in(a, b)} \forall_{x\in[a, b]} \; 0\in[f'(d),f'(c)] \subset\mathbb{R} \quad\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\Delta F=0, \;f(c)=\frac{\left.F(x)\right|_a^b}{\left.x\right|_a^b} \implies f'(x)\geq 0 \;(f'(x) \leq 0)$$

$$\text{while}$$

$$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\Delta F=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}f(x)\Delta x \quad \text{but $f$ is continuous in the domain [a,b], unaffected by $d$ for which the derivative is defined.}$$

$$\text{While we know that $F$ is integrable by definition of the average value:} \\f'(d)\leq0\leq f'(c)=\frac{\left.f(x)\right|_a^b}{\left.x\right|_a^b}$$

Which is unaffected by, $d\neq c$ and all is kept as it is
 Now if you assume that $d$ as an argument of $f$ doesn't makes it an average value, all that needed isn't refuted, and therefore the implication is wrong, and that's what we wanted to show, it can all be showed in short and very formally well written proof.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just a wrong claim. Let $a=0, b=2$ and define $f$ with that way: $f(x)=x$ if $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=-10x+11 $ if $x\in[1,2]$. Then $f$ is continuous and not monotonic on $[0,2]$. But $f_{avg}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-15+11)=-\frac{7}{4}$. But there is only one $x\in [0,2]$ with $f(x)=f_{avg}$.